# android game development using unity 3d

Tags: java, android, unity, javascript, unityscript

I want to learn android game development. I dont have any programing knowledge. So should I learn JAVA and eclispe to develop games for android.

Or should I learn Unity 3d. And is knowledge of java programing is necessary to develop android games in unity? Or knowledge of Javascript/UnityScript will do. Can I develop android games in unity with just JavaScript knowledge??

what are the benefits of unity over Java/eclipse and vice versa when talking of android game dev??

Answer (score 0):

When you build a mobile game in Unity to port onto Android, it creates an .apk package that loads onto your phone and runs. Technically you don't need to know any Java because it builds it all for you, but it would be recommended to learn the basics so that if any edge cases come up when building your apk package, you would be able to figure them out. You could jump right into Unity using UnityScript or JavaScript, but learning the technology it is built on will help you fundamentally with knowing how your game works as a whole and allow you to manipulate your environment to a greater extent. Keep in mind that Unity is a great development platform, but every platform has it's limitations, and if you want to develop a game outside of Unity's restrictions then coding in Java in Eclipse may be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of resources for learning Java focused on android Development right now, as well as Unity 3D. If you plan to develop a game in android with java then start with Java, but don't go over the entire android framework just to switch to Unity.

Try to start with a simple project or tutorial in unity as soon as possible, seeing your game and getting something running through programming in Unity for the first time is a beautiful experience. The longer you wait to do that, chances are you'll get frustated before getting something running.

Unity has C# scripting which is similar in some ways to java, and there are lot more of resources in that languange than in Unityscript. Start small with some tutorials, such as this one: 
http://pixelnest.io/tutorials/2d-game-unity/

Tl;dr; Manage your frustation. Try to get some stuff running as quick as possible and then improve upon it.